# How to filter shapefile using definition query?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-desktop, query, interpolation, definition-query

I have a point shapefile which I want to interpolate using IDW interpolation. However, I want to interpolate only those points which satisfies a certain condition. I need to do it in python and I think that I have to use definition query where only values that are not -999 should be used in the interpolation.

This is my code:

```
outIDW = Idw(fc, zField, cellSize, power, searchRadius)
```

I need to modify somehow the `fc` shape to take into account only values that are different from -999.

This is my query:

```
"P"<>-999
```

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you use to set `fc` - it is always easier to adapt something you have written than to guess what you may have written.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71817/how-to-exclude-stations-from-idw-interpolation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Select Layer by Attributes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Select_Layer_By_Attribute/001700000071000000/) tool. Refer to the tool help for code samples.